# Разбор сложного переключателя цветов из массива

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который при клике поочередно меняет цвет двум блокам.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀                                                          ⠀
.Но я не могу понять, почему при первом клике
**index = 3, а не 0?**

В итоге при первом клике на блок получается **index = 3 + 1 % 4 = 0**⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
берется цвет из массива под позицией **0**
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀     ⠀                 ⠀⠀            Ведь должно же быть при первом клике **index = 0 + 1 % 4 = 1**.

Я запутался, помогите понять почему **при первом клике index = 3, а не 0?**
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ Внизу я пометил странную строчку кода комментарием

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.main');
let colors = ['red', 'black', 'white', '' ];

for(let b of document.querySelectorAll('.block1, .block2')){
b.addEventListener('click', click_block);   
}

function click_block(e){
let index = colors.indexOf(e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor);
alert(e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = colors[(index +1 ) % 4]);// Почему при 1 клике index = 3, а не 0?
}
```

```css
body{
background: orange;     
user-select:none;
}

.main{
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 200px;
position:relative;  
height: 100px;
}

.block0{
height: 100%;   
width:250px;
background: white;
text-align:center;
}

.block1{
height: 100%;   
width:250px;
background: gray;   
text-align:center;
}

.block2{
height: 100%;   
width:250px;
background: gold;   
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

<div class ='block0'>
1 блок - Цвета нет
</div>

<div class="block1">
2 блок - Цвет работает +
</div>

<div class="block2">
3 блок - Цвет работает +
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Уточните зачем вообще % 4 , почему вы просто не смещаете  index  на ++ ?

Comment: Да хорошая идея, но меня интересует почему при первом клике index = 3, а не 0?

Comment: `console.log(e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor);`

Comment: У вас 1 % 4  по модулю 1 по этому и 1. Логично? Тогда как 4 по модулю 4 = 0

Comment: @WalkMess: ваааще ни причём. Проблема в том, что при первом вызове еще не существует никакого _style_, а потому в массиве находит `''`, т.е. последний элемент с индексом 3.

Comment: Я думаю это не так просто, мы никогда не получаем нужный цвет, вычисления вернут строку с цветом типа rgb(255, 0, 0) , таким образом rgb(255, 0, 0) !== red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `style.backgroundColor` - пустая строка, которая есть в Вашем массиве.

```
function click_block(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor);
  ...
```

Comment: Именно так. Хотя подход неверный у автора в целом.

Comment: пустая строка разве даёт сразу + 3 позициям? она же по идее должна дать + 1 позицию?

Comment: indexOf сразу же ищет в массиве ' ', который имеет 3 позицию ?
если так, то почему он ищет его, ведь я не задавал поиск именно ' '

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский Я не понимаю что Вы говорите. `style.backgroundColor` - пустая строка. Индекс пустой строки `3`. Вы прибавляете единицу и находите остаток от деления на `4`. Получается ноль.

Comment: почему indexOf ищет ' ' в массиве? ведь я не задавал поиск именно ' '

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский На первом клике `style.backgroundColor` - пустая строка.

Comment: Разве style.backgroundColor равно style.backgroundColor =' ' ?
Это одно и тоже?

Comment: если не указать значение style.backgroundColor, то по умолчанию берется  ' ' ?

Comment: Там 4 элемент массива = ' '

Comment: @ WalkMess, если не указать значение style.backgroundColor, то по умолчанию берется ' ' ?  Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Могу предположить, что style.backgroundColor - это и есть пустая строка если там ничего нет, консоль не показывает тип undefined

Comment: @WalkMess "консоль не показывает тип undefined" - Вы опять?

Comment: undefined это и есть пустая строка?

Comment: @WalkMess и почему у меня неверный подход? Если так, то покажите свой правильный подход в виде кода.

Comment: @Igor, если не указать значение style.backgroundColor, то по умолчанию берется ' ' ? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: ладно, не хотите отвечать, ставлю все равно плюс и ответ.

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский Вы уже вставили `console.log(e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor);` в свой код?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский: какой прок от демонстрации правильного подхода, если он будет недоступен вашему пониманию, в виду незнания основ. Рекомендую, для начала, освежить знания по темам: Типы данных, Свойства и атрибуты.

Comment: @Igor, да вставил, могли бы понятно и просто ответить мол да, если не указывать значения стилям, то по умолчанию берется пустая строка. Наверное вы сторонник  вычурного стиля.

Comment: @UModeL, вы покажите правильный подход, если вам нетяжело. Я был бы очень рад увидеть правильный подход от великого мудреца =) Основы я знаю, просто иногда забываю, слишком много информации я получаю каждый день.

Answer (score 1):

Я переписал код, вот что у меня получилось. Теперь мы забираем цвета в зависимости от того, что лежит в массиве  colors по определенному условию. Возможно это стоит доработать, но это то, что вам нужно.

```js
//Массив цветов.
let colors = ['rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'];
//Наше правило.
const rules = 1 % 4;
//Текущий цвет в массиве colors
let currentBackgroundColor = '';
//Функция для рандомного числа.
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
//Функция которая получает цвет формата rgb.
const getColorStyles = (element) =>
  window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
//Наше рандомное число, по нему устанавливаем дефолтный цвет.
const initialColorNumber = getRandom(0, colors.length - 1); //

addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const block = event.target.closest('.block');
  if (!block) return;
  //Обновляем цвет.
  currentBackgroundColor = getColorStyles(block);
  //Проверяем, что если отсутствует цвет из массива цветов, устанавливаем цвет рандомный.
  if (!colors.includes(currentBackgroundColor)) {
block.style.backgroundColor = colors[initialColorNumber];
//Обновляем цвет.
currentBackgroundColor = getColorStyles(block);
  }

  //Текущий индекс по которому устанавливаем цвет.
  let currentIndex = colors.indexOf(currentBackgroundColor);
  //Индекс согласно правилу.
  let moduleIndexColor = currentIndex + rules;
  //Учитываем, что такого  index  может не быть, возвращаем правду или ложь.
  const isMax = moduleIndexColor > colors.length - 1 ? true : false;
  if (isMax) {
moduleIndexColor = 0;
  }
  block.style.backgroundColor = colors[moduleIndexColor];
  //Обновляем цвет.
  currentBackgroundColor = getColorStyles(block);
});
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="block">1 блок - Цвет работает +</div>

      <div class="block">2 блок - Цвет работает +</div>

      <div class="block">3 блок - Цвет работает +</div>
    </div> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**Старый вариант, тут мы получаем index  от кол-во элементов.**

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block'); 
const moduleIndex = 0;
const colors = ['red', 'black', 'white', 'white'];

blocks.forEach((block, index) => { 
  block.addEventListener('click', () => {  
    const moduleIndex = (++index) % 4;
    block.style.backgroundColor = colors[moduleIndex];
  })
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="block">1 блок - Цвет работает +</div>

      <div class="block">2 блок - Цвет работает +</div>

      <div class="block">3 блок - Цвет работает +</div>
    </div> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Генератор для цветов.

```js
//Массив цветов.
const colors = [];
const getRandomRgb = () => {
  const num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
  const r = num >> 16;
  const g = (num >> 8) & 255;
  const b = num & 255;
  return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
};

for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  colors.push(getRandomRgb());
}
```

Comment: Неплохо, но в чем отличие от моего кода?

Comment: Ваш код более оптимизирован?

Comment: В том, что он работает так, как вам нужно или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Вы же сами говорили: Уточните зачем вообще % 4 , а сами взяли и написали % 4 :D

Comment: Ну ладно, поставлю плюс за старание =)

Comment: Возможно мое решение не верное. Вам нужно получать  index  не длиною блоков, а длиною цветов, тогда это все меняет.

Comment: Мне удалось добиться нужного результата, попробуйте.  Правило вы можете установить свое.

Comment: Казалось бы простенькая функция переключения цвета, а код у вас большой.
За старание поставил бы второй плюс, но тут можно ставить только 1 =(
Старый вариант мне нравится больше, так как он короче.

Comment: Ну смотрите, вообще код большой из за описания. Да и потом, ваша же версия кода у вас не работает. Моя старая версия не забирает цвета из массива, там imdex учитывается от кол-во самих элементов. По этому в целом - он придельна простой в отличии от работы с массивом цветов.